# Need help in following code snippet

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to call a static function cropImage here is how it looks..

```
 public static Image CropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
 {
        logic goes here..
 }
```

I want to call this function to crop am image how can I do this?
When I tried like this

```
Rectangle objRect=new Rectangle(20,10,200,100);
static_className.CropImage(image,objRect);
```

I got an error saying invalid argument.

Comment: Please post the *exact* error message, and ideally more context (e.g. the type of `image`). Note that C# is case-sensitive, so `cropImage` should be `CropImage` in the calling code.

Comment: Also, please edit the title of your question. This is a very generic title and not useful.

Comment: hi,Jon Skeet. Sorry for that typo error while posting the code .

Comment: object is a C# keyword than cannot be used as a local variable name

Answer (score 0):

```
Image oldImg;

Rectangle objrect=new Rectangle(20,10,200,100);
Image newImage=static_className.cropImage(oldImg,objrect);
```

Comment: I have used an upload control to upload an image and converted image into byte stream and now how can i pass it as a parameter to CropImage Function,

Comment: Use [Image.FromStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx) to load the stream into the Image object, then pass the Image object to the `CropImage` method.